# how to make component re-render when multiple data sources change at meantime

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

```js
const data = createSelector(
  (state: any) => state.pkLiveData,
  (state: any) => state.pkNewAnchorData,
  (pks: LiveBean[], newAnchors: LiveBean[]) => {
    if (pks.length > 0 && newAnchors.length > 0) {
      const lives = pks.concat(newAnchors);
      return lives;
    }
    return [];
  }
);

function select(state: any) {
  return { dataSource: data(state) };
}
```

now, this method was called when pkLiveData or pkNewAnchorData change, that make component re-render twice, but I just want to make component re-render when pkLiveData and pkNewAnchorData changed meantime?